# Java: initialization of private variables in superclass

Tags: java, inheritance, initialization

Will the private variables initialized outside the constructor in the superclass be correctly inherited in the subclass?

For instance, in the following codes, will the private instance variable x be correctly inherited in the subclass? I know that x and y can be accessed in the Square subclass only with the 2 public getters defined in Rectangle. However, if x is initialized outside the constructor, will the subclass still successfully inherit x?

```
public class Rectangle
{
    private int x = 0;
    private int y;
    protected double height;
    protected double length;

    public Rectangle(double length, double height)
    {
        this.height = height;
        this.length = length;
        y = 0;
    }

    public int getx()
    {
        return x;
    }

    public int gety()
    {
        return y;
    }
}


public class Square extends Rectangle
{
    public Square(double side)
    {
        super(side, side);
    }
}
```

Comment: Private members are not inherited at all. They are however initialized as per the program text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it inherits with no problem. If there is no value assigned in constructor, you'll end up in getting default value, since it is an instance member.

Default value of Object is null and each primitive have their default value.

Comment: Do you mean that since I assign a value to private variable x outside the constructor, the assigned value will not be inherited but the default value will be inherited? Say if I change the line `private int x = 0` to `private int x = 1`, will I get the x value as the default 0 or 1 in the subclass? Thank you.

Comment: You'll get 1 :) as it is instance member and assigned.